# Spring Security SessionRegistry returning empty list

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-session

Friends I have search a lot and try every solution available on the internet, but my problem not solved.

I want check (in Spring Boot web application) currently user logged in with the credentials specify in the login page, if there is a session with username currently, then invalidate that first a login again for the request.

I want to ensure there will be one session for the user, if session exist then invalidate and login forcefully.

I am trying to get all the principle from the `SessionRegistry`, but it always returning `[]` empty list even after multiple user logged in the system.

**Here is my spring security config**

```
...
@Autowired private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired private CustomUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler customUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

@Bean
    JCaptchaAuthenticationFilter jCaptchaAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        JCaptchaAuthenticationFilter jCaptchaAuthenticationFilter = new JCaptchaAuthenticationFilter();
        jCaptchaAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        jCaptchaAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(customLoginFailureHandler());
        jCaptchaAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(customUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        return jCaptchaAuthenticationFilter;
    }
@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authProvider;
    }
@Bean
    public CustomLoginFailureHandler customLoginFailureHandler() {
        CustomLoginFailureHandler customLoginFailureHandler = new CustomLoginFailureHandler("/login");
        return customLoginFailureHandler;
    }

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {// @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/", "/register/**", "/email/**", "/captcha.png/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/login/**")
        .permitAll()// Basically I'm allowing parameters for login so
        // .antMatchers("/services/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/forgot/password/**", "/user/verify/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/user/resetPassword*")
        .hasAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE").anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .addFilterBefore(jCaptchaAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession")
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).and()
        .sessionFixation().newSession().and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .invalidateHttpSession(false).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll();
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

    }
....
@Bean
SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {         
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

**Here is i am getting sessions list**

```
List<String> userList = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().stream()
          .filter(u -> !sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(u, true).isEmpty())
          .map(Object::toString)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But above code always return empty list. I have checked is there any double sessionRegistry loading by disabling sessionRepositry, but spring throw exception that bean not found.

Please help friends.

Comment: I wouldn't do this - it doesn't scale well. If you need to search sessions for some reason, consider using [Spring Session](https://projects.spring.io/spring-session/).

Comment: Why? Spring Security already provides this out-of-the-box... Why hack around it... Just set `maxSessionsPreventsLogin` to `false` and this will invalidate the current session and create a new one for the user. Basically what you are attempting to hack around.

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: Not Working. I have set as you have mentioned, but not working. I am able to login in chrome as well as in firefox. I want to allow only one session across the browser as well as machine.

Comment: Debug the code - I suspect that sessions are not being registered correctly. So your `HttpSessionEventPublisher` is not being activated. Either that, or your `Principal` does not correctly override `equals` and `hashCode`. Make sure that the `UserDetails` returns from your `CustomUserDetailsService` correctly implement equality.

Comment: If you're using custom authentication then it will not work out of the box and have to make some configurations. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65542389/9004116